# How can I temporarily disable or mask a few selected monitors without shuffling the application's windows?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a few monitors connected to my laptop and I sometimes want to focus on just one or two monitor without being disturbed by the other monitors. Is there any way in Windows 7 to temporary disable a few selected monitors without shuffling the application's windows?
E.g. it would blacken those monitors, but it wouldn't reorganize the windows around as it would if I was disabling monitors using Windows settings:

[image]

I know that UltraMon has a mirror feature but it takes a while to turn on/off, and I would prefer to disable the monitors rather than using them as mirrors.

Comment: Perhaps there's a way to minimize the brightness of the distracting screens, or run a blank screensaver just on those screens?